# How to seperate multiple matrices from for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I have a function the gives a matrix as a result, since im using a for loop and append the results are 20 matrices in an array. I would like to add up the lower and the upper values of every matrix. np.sum(np.tril(matrix, -1)) will add up the values of all the matrices. Is it possible to do it per matrix? Or can i get 20 seperate matrices to do this?

```
matrix = []
for i in clubs:
    matrix.append(simulate_match(poisson_model, 'ARSENAL', i, max_goals=10))
```

Comment: If you want to get to specific matrix (which is an element in a list), use `matrix[0], matrix[1]` etc.

Comment: oh right, that works. thanks!